# testing methods for MagicSquare

Tags: runtime-error

I want to use the command "java MagicSquare -t" to test the four following methods

I can successfully compile the program but when I run it, I got the following:

```
Full solution:  [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]


Full solution:  [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 0]]


Not rejected:   [[I@7f31245a, [I@6d6f6e28, [I@135fbaa4]


Not rejected:   [[I@45ee12a7, [I@330bedb4, [I@2503dbd3]


Extended [[I@4b67cf4d, [I@7ea987ac, [I@12a3a380] to null


Extended [[I@29453f44, [I@5cad8086, [I@6e0be858] to [[I@29453f44, [I@5cad8086,     
[I@6e0be858]
```

Comment: The error is coming from the extend method that you are not showing us.

Comment: Just added my extend method

Comment: Where does the `size` variable come from in the extend method?

Comment: size is read from command-line using: size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); I just tried to add size = 3; The exception was gone but then I got similar result like the testReject method like [[I@29453f44, [I@5cad8086, [I@6e0be858] to [[I@29453f44, [I@5cad8086, [I@6e0be858]

Comment: I just updated the result after I add size = 3; to the testExtend method. The negativeArraySize exception was removed while there still exist other problems.

Comment: The new error comes from the `next` method.

Comment: and `size` is never set in the first if statement in `main` which is probably why you were getting the first error.

Comment: Do you have any ideas of how to resolve the NullPointerException?

Comment: I would need to see the `next` method.

Comment: Just added that

Comment: It says the error is on line 141 of your code. Can you tell me which line that is?

Comment: if (indexMap[i][j] > -1){

Comment: That either means `indexMap` is never set or the location `indexMap[i][j]` is never set.

Comment: So I set the indexMap and blankIndex in the testNext method and the NullPointerException was solved. I also updated the code and the results. But I still got the wrong test results for next method. When I use next(noNext) in testNext method I think it should return null, but the actual result I get is as the same as the noNext; so, next(noNext) made no change to noNext. Also, when I use next(next) in testNext method I think it should return the next partial solution but I still get the result that made no change to next.

Comment: For one, `blankIndex` and `indexMap` are arrays full of 0's so I don't know what you are doing with them in `next()`

Comment: I'm trying to use the indexMap and blankIndex to keep track of the 0's, so that I could neglect those 0's for the moment. Then I can try to fill in the magic square using continuous indexes. That's because I want to consider the condition when there are mixed 0's and non-0's in the square, that is, it is possible that the 0's are not in a continues order but was randomly inserted into non-0's. Also, I just added the findBlank method.

Comment: I think `findBlank()` should be called inside the next method at the top.

Comment: I tested it myself and got `These can NOT be next'd:
 Nexted [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]] to [[9, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]
These can be next'd:
 Nexted [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 0]] to [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 1]]`. Is this what the output should be?

Comment: I added findBlank at the top of the next method and it works. But I got another exception as: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: add `blankSize = 0;` at the top of `findBlank()`

Comment: It shows like : These can NOT be next'd: Nexted [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]] to [[9, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]], but what I want is [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]] to null; any possible solutions to solve this?

Comment: Did you add `blankSize = 0;`?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: This is the expected output: These can NOT be next'd: Nexted [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]] to null These can be next'd: Nexted [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 0]] to [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int[][] next(int[][] square) {
    findBlank(square);
    // TODO: Complete this method
    int[][] temp = new int[size][size];

    boolean getFlag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            int nextI = i;
            int nextJ = j;
            if (indexMap[i][j] > -1){
                int nextIndex = blankIndex[indexMap[i][j] + 1];
                nextI = nextIndex / size;
                nextJ = nextIndex % size;
            }
            if (((indexMap[i][j] == blankSize - 1 && indexMap[i][j] > -1) || square[nextI][nextJ] == 0) && !getFlag) {
                if(square[i][j] >= size*size ){
                    return null;
                }else{
                    temp[i][j] = square[i][j] + 1;
                    getFlag = true;
                }

            } else {
                temp[i][j] = square[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (Arrays.deepEquals(square, temp)) return null;
    return temp;
}

public static void findBlank(int[][] square){
    blankSize = 0;
    blankIndex = new int[size * size +1];
    indexMap = new int[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if (square[i][j] == 0){
                indexMap[i][j] = blankSize;
                blankIndex[blankSize] = i * size + j;
                blankSize++;
            }
            else{
                indexMap[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After changing the next method like this, my test mode looks good now but the fill-in mode gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: If change like this, I still can't get "null" for can Not be Next'd

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: These can NOT be next'd:
Nexted [[1, 2, 9], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] to [[1, 2, 9], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Comment: Thanks very much. I think without a great change to my code, this issue cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

So I think if I want to keep most of my methods in my code, it is almost impossible to change it to "null." For example, I used {1,2,9},{0,0,0},{0,0,0} to test the next method. I am about to fill in the next blank in fill-in mode, but here I am going to test it. For the first 0 for example, it is almost impossible for the program to tell whether this 0 is the 0 after I filled in 9, or the 0 that I directly filled. If it is when I am filling in, after filling 9, I do need to get the next method and it can be next'd. But if it is when I just about to fill in 0, then I can fill in 1 here.